# How to lazy load an entity attribute using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence, eclipselink

I have a JSF application with JPA and EclipseLink. There is an entity with several attributes including a Lob type to store large binary data.

I need to frequently search the entities and display them in a list. Only when the user wants to view that, the Large Binary data is needed.

Can I have a method to lazy load the binary data? Or do I have to take it out as another entity with one to one relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done easily. Use the following annotation.

@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: With EclipseLink you need to use static or dynamic weaving as well, otherwise FetchType.LAZY takes no effect: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving

Answer (score 10):

You either use bytecode enhancement along with [`@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) on attributes that are to be loaded lazily:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Or you can define multiple subentities to the same database table. Considering you have an `attachment` table that has a `content` column which stores BLOBs.

You can map the non-lazy attributes in a common base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseAttachment {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String name;
 
    @Enumerated
    @Column(name = "media_type")
    private MediaType mediaType;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

If you only need to fetch the non-lazy attributes, you need an entity which just extends the base class:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "attachment")
public class AttachmentSummary extends BaseAttachment {}
```

This will never fetch the `content` column.

If you need to fetch all columns including the `content` one, then you can use this entity:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "attachment")
public class Attachment 
    extends BaseAttachment {
 
    @Lob
    private byte[] content;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vlad Mihalcea, how to do that with spring data jpa using subentities approach?