# Using JPA to retrieve particular many-valued association columns

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is a column that's so huge, it slows the entire query speed.
So i need to ommit the one, only give when actualy needed.
I've tried this solution:

```java
@Query("SELECT new Account (a.name) From Account a Where a.id = :id)
```

The above code will retrive the id column data.When I try to use other getter,obviously the rest property are all null.
but when it comes with other entity relation for example:

```java
//The account entity code
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;
/**
The user side code is ommitted
**/
```

```java
@Query("SELECT new Account (a.name,a.user) From Account a)
```

it will generarte these sql query:

```sql
inner join
        user user3_ 
            on account0_.user_id=user3_.id
```

However, when we using the normal jpa method like

```java
@Query("SELECT a FROM Account a WHERE a.id = :id")
Account getById(UUID id)
```

we can easily get the user entity with the getter method:

```java
Account acc = accountRepository.getById(id);
User user = acc.getUser();
```

Not the inner join sql query;

How can I retrieve the paritcular association entity columns with getter?

Can it be possible to achieve with jpa?

Comment: calling select new Account(X,Y) is a constructor query, and returns plain java objects using only the data you pass in - hence anything else is null, and the java object is unmanaged, so it does not use any mappings you might have - it is effectively a non-entity for all JPA purposes. If you want user to be fetched lazily, it would need to be a managed entity (see @cerdoc's answer), - but why bother? Otherwise, you could query for Account as you have, and then querying for the user separately if/when you need it. You then control if/when/where a query for it gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post should help : [How to lazy load an entity attribute using JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765886/how-to-lazy-load-an-entity-attribute-using-jpa)

Prior I strongly recommend you to understand what lazy loading is in JPA and how it works. These one could help : [What is lazy loading in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192242/what-is-lazy-loading-in-hibernate) and [Difference between FetchType LAZY and EAGER in Java Persistence API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990799/difference-between-fetchtype-lazy-and-eager-in-java-persistence-api)

Comment: Thks, turns out I misunderstand the point, lazy load the attribute can perfectly solve this situation.